# Grails 3 Oauth2 not working with Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat8, spring-security-oauth2, postgresql-9.4, grails-3.0

We have a Grails 3 project where we are using Oauth2 for authentication, we followed a tutorial 
https://github.com/bobbywarner/grails3-oauth2-api

QUERY :-

> curl -X POST -u demo-client:123456 http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=xyz&username=bobbywarner&grant_type=password&scope=read%20write"

OUTPUT:-

> {
>     "access_token": "ff16372e-38a7-4e29-88c2-1fb92897f558",
>     "token_type": "bearer",
>     "refresh_token": "f554d386-0b0a-461b-bdb2-292831cecd57",
>     "expires_in": 43199,
>     "scope": "read write"
>   }

if we use this command, it is generating a token for the user, token expires in 43 mins.

When we are running this application on embedded tomcat it is working fine, but when we create a WAR file and deploy on tomcat, its start behaving weirdly.

1) If deployed on embedded tomcat, the token generated for the user "bobby" is same within 5 sec gap, it is giving same token and an entry is made to "Oauth_access_token". If we use this token for subsequent APIs it works fine.

2) If deployed on tomcat after creating a WAR file, it is creating a new token for each request , even we hit the URL with in 1 secs. After this is use this token for subsequent APIs it gives us the message "token not valid" and delete that token from "Oauth_access_token".

Anybody faced issue like this for Grails 3 application, Please help me to out this.